# Can javascript code tell if the browser is in the background?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, tabbed-browsing

I would like to tell whether my browser's tab is in focus, and whether the browser itself is in the foreground or in the background.

Is there a javascript interface that queries the foreground/background status of the browser?

**Update** Following [Palpatim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603369/palpatim)'s answer below, I found this practical [HTML5Rocks tutorial about the page visibility API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pagevisibility/intro/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your browser support requirements will determine whether this is viable, but the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API) may get you part of the way there.

It doesn't determine foreground/background status; to my knowledge there is no API available to JavaScript that will give you that level of access, so you'd have to rely on a browser plugin to report it. However, it will report whether a page is visible or not, which for many use cases is all that's required.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the page visibility API only detects tab focus, not the background/foreground status of the browser.